# Dealing with Imagery with MonoDevelop and IB... very frustrated with this...

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am very frustrated with how MD and IB seem to not work well together with imagery. Let me explain.

We have a specific look and feel for our iPad app, and most of our controls have some sort of image associated to it (whether that be through .CS code or assigned in IB).

When I import an image into an "images" folder in the project in MonoDevelop, I double click my XIB to open in IB and work with the view visually. I **expect** to see that image that I just imported into MD in the Image drop down for my ImageView... however, I do not and I also see references to images that are no longer in the project (that i have deleted).

Is there some sort of cache mechanism in Xcode/IB that I am not using? I have tried everything i can think of... Clean All... Build All in MD... Clean in IB... nothing seems to  help synchronize my project listings from MD to IB... remove image... reimport into MD... import into IB... nothing seems to trigger a "synchronization" of these files.

Another person was working on the project and just ended up dumping imagery into the root of the project, which I do not like (since I don't want my other developers to have to wade through piles of JPG/PNG files)... so I (assuming MD was at least smart enough to keep references intact) dragged and dropped the images in the root of the project to said "images" folder.... now none of our IB assigned images appear in the iPad app and we get an

"Could not load the  image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.yourcompany.compassipad""

error on each image in the project.

Please, for the love of all things holy, can someone explain this to me? I am perplexed and frustrated by this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode requires that image resources be in the toplevel folder because it refers to them by basename rather than their relative path.

For now, the workaround is to always put your images in the toplevel of your MonoDevelop project, too.

We plan to implement a "Resources" folder in MonoDevelop for you to put your images and other resources that you need Xcode to be able to refer to, so that you can keep your toplevel directory cleaner, but it hasn't been implemented yet.

As far as old images appearing in the dropdowns in Xcode, I'm not sure what is going on there. You could try deleting the 'obj' directory in your project (it holds temporary object files and the temporary Xcode project). MonoDevelop will recreate this folder and generate a new Xcode project when you double-click a .xib.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I really hope this is implemented sooner than later, I might just stick our code/XIB files in their own folder so that developers know where to go, rather than having to wade through the mess of graphic files that gets created... I did fix the old image issue by deleting the obj directory, so thank you for that...

Comment: Another developer and I were just talking about implementing it sooner rather than waiting for MonoDevelop to migrate to MSBuild and having to implement it a second time.